# Accessing java script properties

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am trying to access the properties of javascript objects returned by a ajax response. But it says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined". However if i hard code the same object in a variable and read, i am able to access it.

// code that throws "cannot read........." error

```
$.get('/home/address/city.html', { zipcode: zipcode }, function(ListJSON) {
var tempdata = Stringify(ListJSON);
alert(tempdata);
alert(tempdata["items"][0]["city"]);
```

This gives the output for first alert and second alert throws error.
output of alert(tempdata);

```
{"identifier":"branch","label":"name","items":{"0":{"name":"1234 ABCD AVE         ","branch":"555 ",      "city":"BLR          "}}}
```

// working code

```
$.get('/home/address/city.html', { zipcode: zipcode }, function(ListJSON) {
    var tempdata = {"identifier":"branch","label":"name","items":{"0":{"name":"1234 ABCD AVE         ","branch":"555 ",      "city":"BLR          "}}};
    alert(tempdata);
    alert(tempdata["items"][0]["city"]);
```

output of first alert

```
{"identifier":"branch","label":"name","items":{"0":{"name":"1234 ABCD AVE         ","branch":"555 ",      "city":"BLR          "}}}
```

output of second alert

```
BLR
```

Comment: use `JSON.stringify()` instead `stringify()`

Comment: stringify might make it look pretty in the alert, but it makes it unusable by javascript unless you parse it back to an object. don't stringify it, and don't use alerts to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between them is the hard code working version isn't using string. You are assigning an object to `tempdata` whereas in first version you use `var tempdata = Stringify(ListJSON);` which I assume returns `JSON.stringify(ListJSON)`

You want to work with object, not string

Try

```
$.getJSON('/home/address/city.html', { zipcode: zipcode }, function(ListJSON) {

     alert(ListJSON["items"][0]["city"]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. when i used "alert(ListJSON["items"][0]["city"]);" it worked.. really appreciate your quick response

Comment: Accepted.. :) it takes time to reflect.. thanks again :)